# Disable touchscreen fingerswipes on ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: 22.04, touchscreen, gestures, restricted-access

I want to disable the possibility for the user that he can't use for example the 3-fingerswipe for changing workspaces. I want him to stay being locked in one program and can't access the OS.

I already tried to use tweaks, Wayland and Touchegg, but they didn't help.